# How to get a lua script into lua bytecode?

Tags: c++, lua

If I had a lua script, say

```
print'hi'
```

How would I get the lua bytecode equivalent to it using c++? I'm not sure if I'm explaining this right though. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Do you want to produce a standalone executable? Do you want to call C++ functions from lua? You should probably edit the question until you are fairly sure you *are* explaining it right.

Comment: The relevant C API functions are `luaL_loadfile` or `luaL_loadstring` and `lua_dump`.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load a script and then dump its bytecode.

The relevant C API functions are `luaL_loadfile` or `luaL_loadstring` for loading (they use the primitive `lua_load`) and `lua_dump` for dumping.

Loading is easy to do with these helper functions.

Dumping is a bt more work because of the need to provide a writer function. It may be easier to call `string.dump` after loading:

```
// load script, leave function on the stack
lua_getglobal(L,"string");
lua_getfield(L,"dump");
lua_pushvalue(L,-3);
lua_call(L,1,1);
// string containing bytecode left on the stack
```